Intersection of all divisors in a linear system
I am reading Griffiths-Harris algebraic geometry, and in p.137 it is written that if $E=\{D_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^n}$ is a linear system, then for any $\lambda_0,\dots,\lambda_n$ linearly independent in $\mathbb{P}^n$, $$D_{\lambda_0}\cap \cdots \cap D_{\lambda_n} = \bigcap_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^n} D_\lambda $$
Recall that a linear system is defined to be a linear subspace of $|D|=\mathbb{P}(H^0(M,\mathcal{O}(D)))$ for some divisor $D$. Does the above statement mean that if $f_0,\dots,f_n$ are meromorphic functions on the manifold $M$ with $D_i:=D+(f_i)\geq 0$, then $$D_0\cap \cdots \cap D_n=\bigcap_{a_i\in \mathbb{C}} \left(D+\left(\sum_i a_if_i\right)\right) ?$$
How can we show that if $V\subset M$ is a hypersurface such that $V\subset D_i$ for all $i$, then $V\subset D+(\sum_i a_if_i)$?

I am not too familiar with Griffiths-Harris, so take this answer with a grain of salt (and please correct me if I am wrong).
Your interpretation of the statement seems correct (with the addition that the $f_i$ should be linearly independent).
However, from that you cannot make any conclusion about hypersurfaces $V \subset M$. You should interpret the intersection as an intersection of sets/manifolds, not as an intersection of the support of the divisors.
For example, let $M = \mathbb{P}^2$ with coordinates $x_0, x_1,x_2$ be the projective plane and consider the linear system $\mathbb{P}(H^0(M, \mathcal{O}(H - O))$ of lines vanishing in the origin $O = (1:0:0)$ (where $H$ is the divisor of any line/hyperplane). (EDIT: This is non-standard and probably unfortunate notation, and others might take issue with it). This system is 2-dimensional, and the two (independent) prime examples of such lines are given by $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 0$. Their common intersection is the origin, as is the common intersection of all divisors in the linear series.
In general, if $|D|$ is any divisor on $M$, then what the statement in Griffiths-Harris says is the following: In order to determine the locus of points that is contained in all elements of $|D|$, it suffices to determine the locus of points that is contained in all elements of any given basis of $|D|$.
